# Develop application for iPhone using titanium

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, titanium-mobile

I want to do an app to send messages online, display messages and while receiving a message, show a notification to the user. And it must work in all mobile platforms like ıphone,android.. I've searched and found Phonegap and Titanium and I began to use Titanium. But I was unclear that how to develop application for IOS using titanium?

Comment: I dont know, about Titanium, but if you want to create a Hybrid app, then you can use any JS framework like Sencha or Jquery mobile for UI,and for doing device related feature phonegap is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Experience says that , You should use Titanium for performance issue.
The purpose of PhoneGap is to allow HTML-based web applications to be deployed and installed as native applications. PhoneGap web applications are wrapped in a native application shell, and can be installed via the native app stores for multiple platforms. Additionally, PhoneGap strives to provide a common native API set which is typically unavailable to web applications, such as basic camera access, device contacts, and sensors not already exposed in the browser.

The goal of Titanium Mobile is to provide a high level, cross-platform JavaScript runtime and API for mobile development (today we support iOS, Android, and the browser, with BlackBerry 10 and Windows Phone coming soon and eventually, respectively). Titanium actually has more in common with MacRuby/Hot Cocoa, PHP, or node.js than it does with PhoneGap, Adobe AIR, Corona, or Rhomobile.

for now implemetation titanium , you have to download Titanium Studio , And here you find the latest api to understand how titanium work

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.API

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Iphone emulator wont work on windows so you must have to use MAC machine to build ios apps no matter what framework you use. Titanium or Phone Gap

Answer (score 0):

You need iOS sdk for running your application in iOS simulators also you need it for creating the IPA for installing it on device.

You can't create IPA on Windows machine, you need to create and run iOS app on MAC machine with iOS installed. (Also need android sdk for running it on android emulator)